# Static content generation in Wagtail

Tags: django, wagtail

I'm looking for a way of generating static content (SSG) in wagtail from pre-existing files. I know that there are 100% SSG blog engines (like the excellent pelican) but I'm am wondering if there is a way already exist which enables the import (and updating where appropriate) of content  into a page model.

I did not really want to reinvent the wheel if there is an elegant solution already in the wild.

Answer (score 1):

Wagtail used to use Medusa for static site generation, but it is no longer maintained. The recommended package for static site generation is now `wagtail-bakery`. You can find it here:

https://github.com/mhnbcu/wagtailbakery

It is recommended in the documentation here: http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.9/reference/contrib/staticsitegen.html

Good luck!

Comment: This would indeed generate static html output pages - What I was hoping for was a way to generate content from static files (which can be modified elsewhere) and then use wagtail as the dynamic engine to display the updated contents

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood. I've worked on similar projects but none that fit that description perfectly.